# Can't load package in R batch mode when called from Stata

Tags: r, cmd, stata

I would like to run *from Stata* a simple R script that reads SAS a data file (using the `sas7bdat` package) and writes a Stata data file (using the `foreign` package). I can call the R script with `CMD BATCH` and it runs, but it is unable to use the `sas7bdat` package.

Here is the Stata script.

```
clear
winexec "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH temp.R
```

Here is the R script in `temp.R`.

```
# install.packages("sas7bdat")
# install.packages("foreign")
library("sas7bdat")
library("foreign")

# # test file (my file is local, so this line is commented out)
# download.file(url="http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/logit.sas7bdat", 
#               destfile="temp.sas7bdat",
#               mode="wb")

temp <- read.sas7bdat("temp.sas7bdat")
write.dta(temp, "temp.dta")
```

If I run this script from the R gui, then everything works fine. Likewise I run it from the Windows command prompt with `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH temp.R`. But when I run it from Stata with `winexec` (or `shell`) it fails.

Here is the contents of `temp.Rout` when I run the R script from Stata.

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> # install.packages("sas7bdat")
> # install.packages("foreign")
> library("sas7bdat")
Error in library("sas7bdat") : there is no package called 'sas7bdat'
Execution halted
```

FWIW, I am using Stata 11.2 on Windows 8.1 update 1.

---

Update:

When I run temp.R from the Windows command prompt I get the following.

`C:\Users\richa_000\Desktop\SOquestion>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH temp.R`

yields a `temp.Rout` with

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> # install.packages("sas7bdat")
> # install.packages("foreign")
> library("sas7bdat")
> library("foreign")
> 
> # # test file (my file is local, so this line is commented out)
> # download.file(url="http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/logit.sas7bdat", 
> #               destfile="temp.sas7bdat",
> #               mode="wb")
> 
> temp <- read.sas7bdat("temp.sas7bdat")
> write.dta(temp, "temp.dta")
> 
> proc.time()
   user  system elapsed 
   0.32    0.03    0.34
```

Comment: can you verify that the `sas7bdat` package is installed?

Comment: @ZoëClark - If I run `temp.R` from either the R gui or Windows command prompt the script runs successfully. It is only when I run the script from Stata that I have a problem. Is Stata somehow calling a *different* R that doesn't have these packages?

Comment: I think it's possible. Looks like Stata is using Rv3.1.0; what does the `temp.Rout` file look like when you run it from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: @ZoëClark 3.1.0 is my system version. I will update the question with the other `temp.Rout`.

Comment: In these kinds of cases where it works when being run one way but not another I suggest logging the output of the following commands:  `Sys.info()`, `Sys.getenv()`, and `sessionInfo()`.  If you compare the output of those you'll typically find something that is different which can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Dason Thanks. I am digging through the different `Sys` outputs now.

Comment: @ZoëClark You are correct! Following Dason's point about `Sys.getinfo()` I found that calling `R` from Stata uses a different library (w/o the packages I need). Now just to figure out my the environment variables differ!

Comment: Have you tried using -rsource- from SSC? It makes things like this so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason calling `R` from Stata via `winexec` (or `shell` or `!`) opens a different command prompt than does opening the command prompt from the start window. At least in my install, this loads a different set of environment variables so that the library path is the admin library path.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"
```

However, I use a non-admin library, so that my library path includes both the admin and user libraries.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/richa_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"
```

I tried the Stata package `rsource` from `ssc` (comments above), but this didn't solve the environment problem. My hack is just to append to the library path in the R script as follows.

```
.libPaths(c(.libPaths(), "C:/Users/richa_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"))
```

This solves the problem and yields the correct library path (without creating a second library).